# How to solve problem with searching string function?

Tags: python

I'm learning python(3) myself from book Downey A. "Think Python" and i've problem with task. I have a code that looks like this:

```py
def find(word, letter):
        index = O
    while index < len(word):
        if word[index] == letter:
            return index
        index = index + 1
    return -1
```

I must modify find function so that they have a third parameter (index) in string of word parameter which
identifies the sign the search should start with. I don't know how to solve it. Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

Line 2 has an indentation problem.
The fix is:

```
def find(word, letter):
    index = 0
    while index < len(word):
        if word[index] == letter:
            return index
        index = index + 1
    return -1
```

Comment: If you get more errors. add full code. Or error log. I will help you.

Comment: This code does not run. Index cannot be equal to a letter.That is O, not 0.

Comment: Sorry, i wrote code correct in editor, but incorrect in post. Sorry about that. In editor all tabulators, letters and numbers are ok, as you say. I added index parameter, and removed line 2, but program sill doesn't work the way i want and just return position of the letter from the beggining of the word

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I already have the answer. It should look like this:

```
def find(word,letter,index = 0):
    par = index
    while index < len(word):
        if word[index] == letter:
            return index - par
        index  = index + 1
    return -1
```